# When does DynamoDB throttle request?

Tags: amazon-web-services, metrics, amazon-dynamodb

In the answer to "[How is Amazon DynamoDB throughput calculated and limited?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9423170/how-is-amazon-dynamodb-throughput-calculated-and-limited)" it's been suggested, that DynamoDB throttles request whenever you exceed provisioned throughput on per second basis. However, this contradicts my experience.

I've table where I post multiple rows, often the number of rows way exceeding provisioned write capacity. This happens in short bursts. At one point I've even got 5 minutes average above provisioned capacity. OTOH, 15 minutes average is below capacity. I haven't got any throttled request in that period.

5 minutes average peaks at 8.053 with provisioned capacity of 6:
[image: 5 minutes average]

15 minutes average peaks well below provisioned capacity:

[image]

So when does DynamoDB throttle requests? What kind of average does it take in account? How high above provisioned capacity can the burst be before it gets throttled?

Answer (score 92, accepted):

DynamoDB is designed to ensure that your provisioned capacity is available on a per-second basis. If you provision a table for ten 1kB reads per second then DynamoDB will give you enough capacity to handle that throughput rate. In addition, DynamoDB will sometimes allow you to achieve limited bursting above your provisioned throughput for a short period of time. This is intended to absorb natural variations in customer workloads. This bursting is not guaranteed and it is not always available (and the nature of the available bursting may change over time). As is currently described in the best practices documentation, in order to get the best performance you should have an evenly distributed workload that does not exceed your provisioned capacity and distributes the load evenly over the key space. However, if the reality of production behavior for your application deviates from an evenly distributed workload then DynamoDB may absorb some of the bursts.

As for how much to provision your table, it depends a lot on your workload. You could start with provisioning to something like 80% of your peaks and then adjust your table capacity depending on how many throttles you receive (which you can see in your CloudWatch graphs) and your application’s tolerance for latency induced by retries. Keep in mind that DynamoDB does not allow unlimited bursts above your provisioned capacity. You may be able to absorb short bursts but you cannot sustain a throughput rate above your provisioned capacity level for an extended period of time. The general guidance we can give is to provision for something close to your peaks and then dial down while watching for throttles.

[This answer was posted in AWS forums](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=427062)

Disclaimer: I work for Amazon, DynamoDB team.

Comment: By 80% peaks you're referring to the peaks on the *5 minute average* graph? I other words, let's say I have situation where I have a batch of 60 items every 10 seconds. On per second basis it would be 60, on per minute or longer it's 6. So how high is the peak?

Comment: "So how high is the peak?" I don't think I can tell you that, sorry. All our calculations/accounting is done per second. For bursting traffic we consider a longer time period to analyze the traffic pattern. Finally, as the post indicates, the best course of action is a bit of trial and error, since you know your usage pattern and what tolerance you have for retries/throttling.

Comment: In my own development testing I provisioned a table with 1 write unit and can consistently push 10 writes per second without being throttled, so what @vartec said is consistent with my own experience, however bizarre that may or may not be.

Comment: When it comes to the provisioning, using a tool like Dynamic DynamoDB will automatically scale the provisioning according to your current needs. Thus you wouldn't have to worry about the exact provision need. Read more at the project page http://dynamic-dynamodb.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

Comment: I am load testing my API which has dynamodb in the backend which is performing  a transaction. I am always passing the same primary key for updating the table. It means, I am always updating the same row of that table. I am getting throttle error. 
can you have a look at this ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59929823/not-able-to-solve-throttlingexception-in-dynamodb

Answer (score 25):

There's a [hint in the DynamoDB documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GuidelinesForTables.html#GuidelinesForTables.Bursting) that explains how bursting works:

> When you are not fully utilizing a partition's throughput, DynamoDB retains a portion of your unused capacity for later bursts of throughput usage.  DynamoDB currently retains up five minutes (300 seconds) of unused read and write capacity.

But it also says that you cannot rely on this behavior:

> However, do not design your application so that it depends on burst capacity being available at all times: DynamoDB can and does use burst capacity for background maintenance and other tasks without prior notice.

At least that would explain why it was possible to have a 5 minute average above the provisioned capacity. With the explanation above, it would even be possible to have 15 minute averages (or longer timespans) to be above the provisioned capacity, if you have a spike in the very beginning of the interval and less usage within the 300 seconds before the start of the interval.

Comment: Also mentioned on [this page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/bp-partition-key-design.html#bp-partition-key-throughput-bursting) of the AWS DynamoDB documentation.

Answer (score 0):

DynamoDB provides some flexibility in your per-partition throughput provisioning by providing burst capacity. Whenever you're not fully using a partition's throughput, DynamoDB reserves a portion of that unused capacity for later bursts of throughput to handle usage spikes.

DynamoDB currently retains up to 5 minutes (300 seconds) of unused read and write capacity. During an occasional burst of read or write activity, these extra capacity units can be consumed quickly—even faster than the per-second provisioned throughput capacity that you've defined for your table.

DynamoDB can also consume burst capacity for background maintenance and other tasks without prior notice.