# Sending several hundred thousand JSON objects to a database via API post requests

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, api, amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to send several hundred thousand JSON objects to a database via API post calls. The problem is that when I try to send all those JSON objects to the database, with seperate calls for each object, I get a lot of HTTP errors, mostly 400.

My question is, is there a better way to send all the JSON objects to the databse? Could I send them all at once? Wait between API calls?

I do not if it's important but I'm trying to send the data to a DynamoDB via a AWS API.

Comment: An error `400` can be caused by all sorts of issues because it's such a generic code (client error). I think more information is needed - what does your API look like? What object are you sending? What object (schema) does you DB expect? etc.

Answer (score 2):

You can write items in **batches**. See:

- AWS command line interface [batch-write-item](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/dynamodb/batch-write-item.html)
- AWS API [BatchWriteItem](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_BatchWriteItem.html)

You could also provision more capacity in DynamoDB. [This question about throttling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16980678/when-does-dynamodb-throttle-request) in DynamoDB could be useful.  That might be the reason why you're getting HTTP 400 errors (more details about the HTTP error message you get would be useful).

Comment: Thank you very much! This got me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/CommonErrors.html) states that an error 400 can be a ThrottlingException `The request was denied due to request throttling.`

If this is the case, you have three choices.

1) Limit the number of individual POST calls that are sent to the API per second from your code via a queuing system.

2) As recommended in a previous answer, you could use the [batch functionality](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_BatchWriteItem.html).

3) Increase the capacity of the table. This can be achieved via the console by selecting the table, going into the capacity tab and increasing the `Write capacity units`

Comment: Thank you very much! I will definitely try this.