# Not able to solve throttlingException in DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, serverless, aws-xray

I have a lambda function which does a transaction in DynamoDB similar to this.

```
try {
        const reservationId = genId();
        await transactionFn();
        return {
            statusCode: 200,
            body: JSON.stringify({id: reservationId})
        };

        async function transactionFn() {
            try {
                await docClient.transactWrite({
                    TransactItems: [
                        {
                            Put: {
                                TableName: ReservationTable,
                                Item: {
                                    reservationId,
                                    userId,
                                    retryCount: Number(retryCount),
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            Update: {
                                TableName: EventDetailsTable,
                                Key: {eventId},
                                ConditionExpression: 'available >= :minValue',
                                UpdateExpression: `set available = available - :val, attendees= attendees + :val, lastUpdatedDate = :updatedAt`,
                                ExpressionAttributeValues: {
                                    ":val": 1,
                                    ":updatedAt": currentTime,
                                    ":minValue": 1
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ]

                }).promise();
                return true
            } catch (e) {
                const transactionConflictError = e.message.search("TransactionConflict") !== -1;
                // const throttlingException = e.code === 'ThrottlingException';
                console.log("transactionFn:transactionConflictError:", transactionConflictError);
                if (transactionConflictError) {
                    retryCount += 1;
                    await transactionFn();
                    return;
                }
                // if(throttlingException){
                //
                // }
                console.log("transactionFn:e.code:", JSON.stringify(e));
                throw e
            }
        }
```

It just updating 2 tables on api call. If it encounter a transaction conflict error, it simply retry the transaction by recursively calling the function.

The **eventDetails** table is getting too much db updates. ( checked it with aws Contributor Insights) so, made provisioned unit to a higher value than earlier.

[image]

For **reservationTable** Provisioned capacity is on Demand.

When I do load test over this api with 400 (or more)  users using JMeter (master slave configuration) I am getting Throttled error for some api calls and some api took more than 20 sec to respond. 
When I checked X-Ray for this api found that, DynamoDB is taking too much time for this transasction for the slower api calls.

[image]

[image]

Even with much fixed provisioning ( I tried on demand scaling too ) , I am getting throttled exception for api calls.

```
ProvisionedThroughputExceededException: The level of configured provisioned throughput for the table was exceeded.
Consider increasing your provisioning level with the UpdateTable API.
```

**UPDATE**

And one more thing. When I do the load testing, I am always uses the same eventId. It means, I am always updating the same row for all the api requests. I have found [this](https://www.bluematador.com/docs/troubleshooting/aws-dynamo-throttling) article, which says that, a single partition can only have upto 1000 WCU. Since I am always updating the same row in the eventDetails table during load testing, is that causing this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact error and it helped me to change the *On Demand* to *Provisioned* under Read/write capacity mode. Try to change that, if that doesn't help, we'll go from there.

Comment: No. It didnt helped me. I tried various provisioned capacity from 2000 WCU to 5000 WCU, it shows the same error.

Comment: I have an update in my question. Can you check that ?

Answer (score 0):

From the link you cite in your update, also described in an AWS help article [here](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/on-demand-table-throttling-dynamodb/), it sounds like the issue is that all of your load testers are writing to the same entry in the table, which is going to be in the same partition, subject to the hard limit of 1,000 WCU.

Have you tried repeating this experiment with the load testers writing to different partitions?

Comment: Please try to be more affirmative when posting an answer. Is this an answer to the problem or is it just a request for clarification? In the latter case then you should post a comment (when you have the minimum reputation required), otherwise only answer the questions you are sure you know the answer to.