# How often does AWS DynamoDB reset the throughput limit

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

If you have 1 read unit provisioned for a DynamoDB table, you can still read more than 1 item/second, as long as you don't go over the limit within a specific interval, see [this page](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/QueryAndScanGuidelines.html) for information about intervals.

How long are these intervals? 1 minute, 1/2 an hour, an hour...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, Amazon don't publish that information, but [from other people's experiments](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19142987/3576887), it looks like it's about 5 minutes

Comment: I don't understand what that means, can I read over 1 item/second for 5 minutes? How much over?

Comment: I haven't used DynamoDB for a while, so this might have changed, but yes, afaik you can use 300 read units in a few seconds, and then it'll be blocked for the next 5 minutes.